# What's a good approach to managing the db connection in a Google Cloud SQL (GAE) Python app?

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, webapp2, google-cloud-sql

I'm just learning Google App Engine and am trying to figure out a good approach to managing my database connection to a Google Cloud SQL instance (if you haven't used GC-SQL, basically, it's MySQL in the cloud, with a few limitations).

I'm using the python (2.7) GAE environment with the webapp2 framework for handling requests.  I know the FAQ says that it's recommended that a new connection to the DB be made with each request, but I don't know what the recommended way of closing the connection is. Each time I try to drop tables during development, the GC-SQL hangs and "show processlist" shows that there are a bunch of processes (likely because I'm not closing the DB) and that one of them is waiting for a lock (likely the process trying to drop the tables).  This is annoying and forces me to restart the GC-SQL instance (like restarting mysql-server service, I imagine).  There are also occasional DB hiccups that I believe are related to the fact that I'm not really closing my DB connection.

So, for example, should I have a destructor on my webapp2.Requesthandler subclass instance to disconnect from the DB? GAE objects seem to be cached sometimes, so that's also something to consider.  I suppose I could just connect/query/disconnect for each query, but this seems suboptimal.

I know this is a vague question, but I'm hoping someone who's played in this area can thow some tips my way.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I tried implementing a wrapper around methods that need a cursor, using Shay's answer as a starting point. I'm getting GAE errors.  Here's a new question specific to that: [What are the connection limits for Google Cloud SQL from App Engine, and how to best reuse DB connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10424442/379037)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Google Cloud SQL, but couldn't you use a WSGI middleware to open and close the connection?

Comment: Thank you Guido. I'm humbled.  Unfortunately, webapp2, which is the WSGI framework I'm using under GAE, doesn't seem to include a DB API wrapper.  I'm too deep in my project and short on time to refactor it for another framework.  So, I'm stuck managing the DB connection manually.  Any other hints? :-)  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- my proposal is simply that you write a tiny piece of WSGI middleware yourself that opens and closes the DB connection.  That's still manual to me (since you write the code) and doesn't seem incompatible with webapp2, which as you say is WSGI compliant.  What am I missing?  (OTOH a decorator seems a fine idea too.)

Comment: Ahhh.  Sorry.  I'm completely new to web dev with python and now realize I didn't actually understand your answer before. :-) Now that I looked it up and realize that "WSGI middlware" != web framework compatible with WSGI, it makes a lot of sense. A WSGI Filter/middleware which wraps the webapp2.RequestHandler to connect and then later disconnect from the DB, as you suggest, makes sense and is in the spirit of Shay's answer as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Here is a complete example of the helloworld example app from the [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/developers_guide_python).  It is based on snippets from [Shay Erlichmen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10162674/1373093) and [JJC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424442), but this version is threadsafe.

You can use it like this:

```
  @with_db_cursor(do_commit = True)
  def get(self, cursor):
        cursor.execute('SELECT guestName, content, entryID FROM entries')
```

---

app.yaml

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

---

helloworld.py

```
import cgi
import logging
import os
import threading
import webapp2

from google.appengine.api import rdbms

_INSTANCE_NAME = <name goes here>

def _db_connect():
  return rdbms.connect(instance=_INSTANCE_NAME, database='guestbook')

_mydata = threading.local()

def with_db_cursor(do_commit = False):
  """ Decorator for managing DB connection by wrapping around web calls.

  Stores connections and open cursor count in a threadlocal
  between calls.  Sets a cursor variable in the wrapped function. Optionally
  does a commit.  Closes the cursor when wrapped method returns, and closes
  the DB connection if there are no outstanding cursors.

  If the wrapped method has a keyword argument 'existing_cursor', whose value
  is non-False, this wrapper is bypassed, as it is assumed another cursor is
  already in force because of an alternate call stack.
  """
  def method_wrap(method):
    def wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if kwargs.get('existing_cursor', False):
        # Bypass everything if method called with existing open cursor.
        return method(self, None, *args, **kwargs)

      if not hasattr(_mydata, 'conn') or not _mydata.conn:
        _mydata.conn = _db_connect()
        _mydata.ref = 0
        _mydata.commit = False

      conn = _mydata.conn
      _mydata.ref = _mydata.ref + 1

      try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        try:
          result = method(self, cursor, *args, **kwargs)
          if do_commit or _mydata.commit:
            _mydata.commit = False
            conn.commit()
          return result
        finally:
          cursor.close()
      finally:
        _mydata.ref = _mydata.ref - 1
        if _mydata.ref == 0:
          _mydata.conn = None
          logging.info('Closing conn')
          conn.close()
    return wrap
  return method_wrap


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @with_db_cursor(do_commit = True)
  def get(self, cursor):
        cursor.execute('SELECT guestName, content, entryID FROM entries')
        self.response.out.write("""
          <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
          <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
            <head>
               <title>My Guestbook!</title>
            </head>
            <body>""")
        self.response.out.write("""
              <table style="border: 1px solid black">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="35%" style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Name</th>
                    <th style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">Message</th>
                    <th style="background-color: #CCFFCC; margin: 5px">ID</th>
                  </tr>""")
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
          self.response.out.write('<tr><td>')
          self.response.out.write(cgi.escape(row[0]))
          self.response.out.write('</td><td>')
          self.response.out.write(cgi.escape(row[1]))
          self.response.out.write('</td><td>')
          self.response.out.write(row[2])
          self.response.out.write('</td></tr>')

        self.response.out.write("""
          </tbody>
            </table>
              <br /> No more messages!
              <br /><strong>Sign the guestbook!</strong>
              <form action="/sign" method="post">
              <div>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" style="border: 1px solid black"></div>
              <div>Message: <br /><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
              <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>""")

class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  @with_db_cursor(do_commit = True)
  def post(self, cursor):
    fname = self.request.get('fname')
    content = self.request.get('content')
    # Note that the only format string supported is %s
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO entries (guestName, content) VALUES (%s, %s)', (fname, content))

    self.redirect("/")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
    [('/', MainPage),
     ('/sign', Guestbook)],
    debug=True)
```

Comment: Excellent! This will help future readers a good deal.  Thanks!  One probably stupid MySQL (err, Google Cloud SQL) question, though.  If there are multiple open cursors for a given connection, in the above code, and one of the cursors was created with do_commit=True while the others were not, wouldn't the one commit cause all the other cursors' changes to be committed, invalidating the do_commit=False set for the others?  Maybe I should ask Shay this, but thought I'd ask you first. Thanks!

Comment: I think you're right.  I don't know that it really makes sense to have multiple cursors active at the same time (or that it even works at all).  The ref counting is mostly to figure out when to close the connection.  Probably better to do something more explicit.

Comment: I can confirm that this method seems to work fine for my much more complex GAE app with Google Cloud SQL.  Thank you again Ken!

Comment: Ken.  I sharing a connection between threads okay in the Google implementation of the MySQL interface from Python?  In the MySQLdb documentation, it says that connections should NOT be shared between threads.  I'm having issues again and I'm wondering if this might be a cause.

Comment: Shay, os.environ doesn't allow multiple threads to be using unique connections.  They'll all use the same connection, but connections aren't threadsafe.

Comment: @KenAshcraft I think when os.environ was implemented for AppEngine PY27 the AppEngine team made sure that each thread has its own copy of os.environ ["But what if my app makes use of 'os.environ' or other CGI-isms, you ask? All is not lost. The smart folks on the Python 2.7 runtime team foresaw that some apps will inevitably do this, and built in a workaround for them. 'os.environ' and a few other bits and pieces are now "thread local" on the 2.7 runtime"](http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe)

Comment: From tests it seem each request is run in its own entirely new thread —with it's own thread.local()— thus requests never reuse the same connection and all requests open and close a connection to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a decorator to handle SQL connection, feel free to flame :)

```
# Here is how you use the decorator from below
# the open, commit, and close is done by the decorator 
@need_cursor(do_commit = True)
def get(self, cursor, request): # cursor param is added by the decorator
    execute_sql(cursor, sql)
```

---

```
def need_cursor(do_commit = False):
    def method_wrap(method):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            conn = os.environ.get("__data_conn")

            # Recycling connection for the current request
            # For some reason threading.local() didn't worked
            # and yes os.environ suppose to be thread safe 
            if not conn:                
                conn = create_connection() # You need to implement this
                os.environ["__data_conn"] = conn
                os.environ["__data_conn_ref"] = 1
            else:
                os.environ["__data_conn_ref"] = 
                    os.environ["__data_conn_ref"] + 1

            try:
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                try:
                    result = method(cursor, *args, **kwargs)

                    if do_commit or os.environ.get("__data_conn_commit"):
                        os.environ["__data_conn_commit"] = False
                        conn.commit()

                    return result                    
                finally:
                    cursor.close()                
            finally:
                os.environ["__data_conn_ref"] = 
                    os.environ["__data_conn_ref"] - 1
                if os.environ["__data_conn_ref"] == 0:
                    os.environ["__data_conn"] = None
                    conn.close()        

        return wrap

    return method_wrap
```

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know the GAE environment could be written to.  Is there any particular reason you implemented this with a decorator rather than just a straight method? Thanks!

Comment: @JJA Its easier to do AOP with decorators

Comment: Huh, I hadn't heard of AOP before, but it's a good concept to keep in mind in this instance.  Definitely DB connection maintenance is a "cross-cutting" aspect.  I felt this as I was working on my code and needed to talk to the DB connection from several modules.  I just didn't have a name for that annoyance until now.  Thank you! :-)

Comment: Here's a link to an article on AOP for future readers of this question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Comment: Hi @Shay.  I tried implementing your suggestion and am getting "ApplicationError 1033 Instance has too many concurrent requests." after firing up a couple hundred test clients of my app.  Have you ever come across this?  I can't find any hits online.  See my question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10424442/379037  Thanks again for your suggestion, I still believe it's a good one.  Just to clarify, have you tried this on Google Cloud SQL via a GAE app? Thanks.

Comment: @JJC I wrote this for using it on cloud SQL, and I use it all the time. Have you check that the connections are actually getting closed?

Comment: Yes, I tried pinging the connection before and after the close.  It works before, but fails after.  Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the new question with my code. Please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10424442/379037

Comment: Shay, how do you deal with the fact that a commit on one cursor (or a rollback) will affect other open cursors?  It seems that MySQLdb (and, I'm assuming GCSQL) doesn't support multiple cursors per connection (allows it, but it leads to data consistency problems).

Comment: @JJC not a big issues for me because all the insert are done from a single location, you can cancel the connection caching and it will work for you.

Comment: @JCC one more thing you can do is not to use connection sharing in case do_commit is true

Comment: Thanks.  This is an issue I hadn't thought of (i.e. I assumed each cursor was a separate transaction), and it ended up causing problems for me.  My application is write-heavy, so pretty much all the cursors are doing inserts/updates.  So, I think I'll have to avoid connection sharing altogether. :-(

Comment: No problem. You can thank me by upvoting more of my comments and questions. :-P

Answer (score 2):

This is my approach, that considers possible exceptions. I use this approach on a production environment and works well:

```
def _create_connection(schema):

    if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and
        os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
        socket = '/cloudsql/%s' % env.DB_INSTANCE_NAME
        return MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket=socket, user=env.DB_APP_USER,
                               passwd=env.DB_APP_PASS, db=schema)
    else:
        return MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306,
                               user=env.DB_APP_USER, passwd=env.DB_APP_PASS,
                               db=schema)


def with_db(commit=False, schema=env.DB_SCHEMA_NAME):

    def method_wrap(method):
        @functools.wraps(method)
        def wrap(self, *args, **kwds):
            # If needed,a connection pool can be added here.
            connection = _create_connection(schema)

            try:
                cur = connection.cursor()
                self.cur = cur
                self.conn = connection

                result = method(self, *args, **kwds)

                if commit:
                    connection.commit()

            except OperationalError as e:

                logging.error('Operational error.\r\nSQL exception: {},\r\n'
                              'Last Query: {}'.format(e, cur._last_executed))

                if commit and connection.open:
                    connection.rollback()
                raise

            except MySQLError as e:

                try:
                    warns = self.conn.show_warnings()
                    error = self.conn.error()
                except:
                    warns = ""
                    error = ""

                logging.error('Try to rolling back transaction.\r\nSQL exception: {},\r\n'
                              'Last Query: {},\r\nConn warn: {},\r\nError: {}'
                              .format(e, cur._last_executed, warns, error))


                if commit and connection.open:
                    connection.rollback()
                raise

            except Exception as e:
                logging.error('Try to rolling back transaction. Non SQL exception: {0}'.format(e))

                if commit and connection.open:
                    connection.rollback()
                raise

            finally:
                connection.close()

            return result
        return wrap
    return method_wrap
```

You can use it like this:

```
@with_db(commit=True)
def update_user_phone(self, user, phone):
    self.cur.execute(_SQL_UPDATE_USER_PHONE, (phone, user.id))

    # add or replace existing user to cache
    user.phone = phone
    self._update_user_cache(user)
```