# Does a commit on a Python MySQLdb cursor affect transactions in progress in another cursor?

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, mysql-python, google-cloud-sql

If I have multiple cursors (each in a different thread, for example) generated from the same DB connection, does a commit on one cursor (e.g. in Python: cursor.execute('COMMIT')) affect transactions in progress on another cursor within the same connection?  If so, should I always only have one cursor per DB connection, in order to avoid cross-cursor issues like this?   (Also, if you know, does this also apply to Google Cloud SQL?)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably. `MySQLdb` specifies a [`threadsafety`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)- attribute of 1, which means you shouldn't share connections (and therefore cursors) on multiple threads without manual synchronisazion.

you should better use some form of connection pooling.

Comment: trying it out also confirmed it.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Cloud SQL, you should have only one cursor at a time per DB connection.  On the server side, there is a single datastructure per connection that keeps track of the current transaction/query.  If you have multiple cursors, they will step on each other.

I suggest opening a connection at the beginning of every http request and closing it at the end.  Here is [some sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158805/whats-a-good-approach-to-managing-the-db-connection-in-a-google-cloud-sql-gae/10438622#10438622) for that.

Comment: Thanks Ken.  Your code example is helpful, but if sharing connections is dangerous across threads, should the wrapper even be reusing the same connection?